# Simple JSFiddle. When I run a function it outputs the code instead of result

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

In this simple example I have a function that returns a text string. When I try to output the result of the function it just outputs the code of the function. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/VQz73/

Comment: you have to actually execute the function `document.write( hello() );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.write(hello());
```

not

```
document.write(hello);
```

The former is outputting the result of the function call. The latter is outputting a reference to the function itself. You weren't invoking it.

As a sidenote, `document.write` is very old school and has almost no use these days. If you're new to JavaScript I would suggest looking into other means of output such as DOM scripting, e.g.

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = hello();
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I am a bit of a js Rookie.